# how do I create a Java swing UI like this?

Tags: java, swing

Below UI is something I'd like to aim for. But I have no idea, how they have the "skin" of the app. On my end, the Java application looks like it was made in 1990s. I want to change a look to a more modern style.

What components are they using possibly here? JSplitpane for one. but I'm not sure how they created that "Dokument/Vorschau" tabs.

[image]

Comment: The closest I can think of similar L&F like above is NimRod L&F (a free license L&F) http://personales.ya.com/nimrod/screenshots-en.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First using a look and feel like **Nimbus**, can easily change the look of your application to a have a more modern feel.

Second, you will need to customize the font, color, borders, node icons, etc. of each component type to achieve a non-standard look.  Some of these can be changed with updates to the `UIDefaults` of the look and feel but many will be made by calling methods on the specific instance of the component you are dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

Try a javax.swing.JTabbedPane.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to change the complete look-and-feel of your application from scratch, you should take a look at [Synth L'n'F](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synth_Look_and_Feel). You can define style and appearance of components and bind them to components which match certain criteria.

(My opinion on that matter: heavily themed apps usually look and feel out-of-the-place and only make it harder to use the app, so I'd actually try to avoid themeing)